# How can I use [Authorize] in IndentityServer3 within the IdentityServer itself?

Tags: identityserver3

I've set up an IdentityServer3 server with IdentityManager and MembershipReboot and have successfully managed to implement Bearer authentication across a few different ASP.NET Web API servers and a couple of Angular JS clients.

I'd like to be able to set up an endpoint on the IdentityServer3 Web API project itself that users can go to in order to edit their email-addresses, password, etc. In order to do this, I need to be able to use the [Authorize] attribute inside one of the controllers running on the IdentityServer3 server. I'm having trouble trying to find out how to do this.

In projects that use my IdentityServer3 server, I simply add something like:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(...);
```

I wondered if I could just do the same in the server itself, but it wouldn't be Bearer token authentication in this case.

I just want to add an MVC page to the auth server that I can redirect to from the client applications to allow the user to modify their details. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an OWIN Context Environment extension in IdentityServer3, namely [`GetIdentityServerFullLoginAsync`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Extensions/OwinEnvironmentExtensions.cs#L508), which retrieves the logged in user (stored in a cookie).

I can create a new Action that uses this to retrieve the logged in user and display their details. I can also add endpoints for updating the password, etc, so long as I protect against CSRF in the usual MVC way.